# empty $file[0] and $file[1]

Tags: php, file

I uploaded this on 000webhost, and it doesn't update the imagename and the imagetype on my database.

```
<form action="cpanel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="Browse" />
<input type="submit" name="btnchange" value="Submit Changes"/>
</form
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnchange'])){

$loc = "pictures/";
$file = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$sql = "UPDATE `tbluser` SET imagename =  '" .$file[0]. "', imagetype = '" .$file[1]. "' where uname = '" .$_SESSION['user']. "'";

$query = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die ("Database Query Failed!"); 
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$newname = "$id.$file[1]";
$path = "$loc$newname";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);
}
```

Comment: Did you start the session? Add error reporting and check for real errors on DB, rather than a simple echo message.

Comment: Yes, I did start the session. Okay let me try. Just one more thing, I wonder whenever I click the 'btnchange' button, the webhost sql automatically logs me out. Is it normal?

Comment: $_FILES["file"]["name"] returns only name of the file, not type of that file

Comment: $id = mysql_insert_id(); returns id only if you have used INSERT statement. does not work with UPDATE.

Comment: **$imagename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$imagetype=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
$imagesize=$_FILES["file"]["size"];**

Comment: 1 last question=> Are you on a free host or an upgraded in 000webhost.com?

Comment: @CodingHorror I can answer that. Uploading is allowed on that host. One thing it doesn't let people do with free accounts, is to connect with MySQL through remote connection. Mail is even available with free accounts.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: You have also omitted the the most important tag in your form-**<input type="hidden"name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"value="write_in_bites">** It is required on that host, i think so.

Comment: @Fred-ii- here are the errors: Undefined index: file in ($file = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]); and move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);) and Undefined offset: 1 in $sql.

Comment: @CodingHorror i'll try that, but I wonder why it works on a localhost.

Comment: 000Webhost has a file size limit only upto 2M? have you faced this issue on their server?

Comment: @CodingHorror not that i know of. I'm only trying to upload a 93kb file. thanks for helping me by the way. :)

Comment: [Tizag wrote a very helpful tutorial on File upload](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) try their examples

Answer (score 0):

First of, I would recommend you NOT to use mysql_query. Instead, use PDO\mysqli.
The reason it does not work could be because you did not start your session before using $_SESSION['user'].

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

For versions of PHP < 5.4.0

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: I started my session. But I wonder if there is something wrong with the php coding.